# wordpress adminpanel login redirect to same login page on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

i have live working site when i try to configure site locally on localhost using **xampp + external mysql** whole site works fine.

when i try to login to admin panel using this link

> http://localhost/dentabad/wp-login.php
>
> it redirects to
>
> http://localhost/dentabad/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdentabad%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

with wrong user name and password it shows error **username or pass not valid** but with correct username + pass it continue on refreshing login page.

i have tried many thing but no luck like [premium.wpmudev.org](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/setting-up-xampp/?ptm=b&utm_expid=3606929-108.O6f5ypXuTg-XPCV9sY1yrw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.pk%2F) and [fancytheme.com](https://fancythemes.com/fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-redirecting-issue/) also [www.wpproblems.com](http://www.wpproblems.com/login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-error/) , [manny stackoverflow questions]

there is my **.htaccess** file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dentabad/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dentabad/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

any suggestions what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

delete your htaccess file and then try. if still not works then rename your plugins folder.

Comment: try to reset password manually from phpmyadmin and then test.

Comment: im using external mysql db , not builtin xammp.

Comment: also if m enter wrong pass it shows error "username/pass incorrect"

Comment: how you have made configuration in wp-config.php?

Comment: function admin_default_page() {
  return '/new-dashboard-url';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');

Comment: functions.php in your theme. then replace /new-dashboard-url to wp-admin